# Why is Wechat consuming a huge amount of storage

Tags: internal-storage

I am a very light wechat user, using it only for work to communicate with suppliers, yet my wechat constantly gets bloated, have had to clear it every month or so.

Below is an image with wechat consuming a large part of my internal storage.

[image]

Often people talk about the media taking most of the data, but this doesnt seem to add up with this image

[image]

Edit: The second ~13GB is also related to wechat, it is under com.tencent.mm/MicroMsg/xlog/...

After a app info -> clear storage it looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Did you try this.. Go to WeChat-->Me-->Settings-->General-->Storage clear cache and temporary files. Set auto-delete temp pics and videos after specific time if there is an option

Comment: You can see above the cache is 11kb. I am not a heavy user of wechat, and with 1 active thread with very low traffic i dont see 13 gb of media coming from it.